# Is $\sum_i x_i \sum_j y_j$ a valid inner product for $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products

An exercise in my book asks you to check whether the following is a valid inner product for $\mathbb{R}^n$:
$$
\left<x,y\right>=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i \sum_{j=1}^{n}y_j
$$
The answer given is "No", but to me it seems to satisfy all the axioms (see below).

---

\begin{array}
.\left<y,x\right> &= \sum_i y_i \sum_j x_j\\
&= \sum_i x_i \sum_j y_j\\
&= \left<x,y\right>
\tag{1}
\end{array}

\begin{array}
.\left<x,y+z\right> &= \sum_i x_i \sum_j(y_j+z_j)\\
&= \sum_i x_i \left(\sum_j y_j + \sum_j z_j\right)\\
&= \sum_i x_i \sum_j y_j + \sum_i x_i \sum_j z_j\\
&= \left<x,y\right> + \left<x,z\right>
\tag{2}
\end{array}

\begin{array}
a\left<cx,y\right> &= \sum_i (cx_i)\sum_j y_j\\
&= c\sum_i x_i \sum_j y_j\\
&= c\left<x,y\right>
\tag{3}
\end{array}

\begin{array}
a\left<x,x\right>&=\sum_i x_i \sum_j x_j\\
&=\left(\sum_i x_i\right)^2\\
&>0 \quad \textrm{if }x\neq 0
\tag{4}
\end{array}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $(4)$ you say $<x,x> = (\sum _{i}x_i)^2>0$  if $x\neq 0.$

However try $x=(1,-1,0,\cdots,0)$.

Comment: Oh, subtle. Thanks.